# Google Drive Java SDK API - How do shared documents get treated when calling the children() function?

Tags: google-drive-api

Let's say you want to list all of a Google drive user's content.

You would naturally call `drive.files().get("root").execute()`

I noticed that this file both returns files you *own* and files you *are shared*.

My question is - what structure are these coming in and what order? Is it just going to be some random mix of shared and owned files?

Answer (score 1):

well I would have though that that would return an error as [files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get) requires a file id to be passed and root is a folder not a file.

On the chance that you meant [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) then its pretty much random the order it is returned. However you can supply the q parameter to search for just one or the other you can also supply orderBy to sort the return results.   Check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list#parameters)

Comment: Sorry yes I meant `files.list()`. I am not sure why I said `files.get` as yes you are correct that would get nothing.

Comment: @DalmTo thank you. sounds like the answer is "random"

Comment: Wild guess is that its based on the last time the file was used / created.  However I never really dug into it I normally order them after they are returned to me anyway.